# Linear independence of a pair of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

We have vectors $A=[-9,\alpha,7]^T$ and $B=[\beta,3,-7]^T$

Find values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in a way that group **{a,b}** is linearly independent.

I know how to find if two vectors are linearly independent or dependent if they have nonvariable scalars but I have no idea how you would go about solving this with variable scalars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda, \mu$ be scalars such that:

$$0 = \lambda A + \mu B = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}{-9}\\{\alpha}\\{7}\end{bmatrix} + \mu \begin{bmatrix}{\beta}\\{3}\\{-7}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{-9\lambda + \mu\beta}\\{\alpha\lambda+3\mu}\\{7\lambda-7\mu}\end{bmatrix}
$$
We are trying to solve for $\lambda, \mu$ in terms of $\alpha, \beta$ and then see for which values of $\alpha, \beta$ can we conclude $\lambda = \mu = 0$.

The last equation $7\lambda-7\mu = 0$ gives $\lambda = \mu$. Using this in the first two equations yields:

$$0 = \alpha\lambda+3\mu = (\alpha + 3)\lambda$$
$$0 = -9\lambda + \mu\beta = (\beta - 9)\lambda$$

Now if any of $\alpha + 3$ or $\beta - 9$ is nonzero, we could conclude $\lambda = 0$ and therefore $\mu = 0$. So, $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent in this case.

However, if both $\alpha + 3 = \beta - 9 = 0$, then the last two equations are $0 = 0$, which does not imply anything.

In that case we have $\alpha = -3$ and $\beta = 9$ so:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}{-9}\\{\alpha}\\{7}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{-9}\\{-3}\\{7}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}{\beta}\\{3}\\{-7}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}{9}\\{3}\\{-7}\end{bmatrix}$$

We can see that $A + B = 0$ so they are linearly dependent.

Thus, $A$ and $B$ are linearly independent if and only if $(\alpha, \beta) \ne (-3, 9)$.

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors are linearly dependent if and only if one of them is the other one mutiplied by a scalar. Since the third coordinates of $A$ and $B$ are $7$ and $-7$ respectivly, they are linearly dependent if and only if each of them is the other one multipliad by $-1$. That is, they are linearly dependent if and only if $B=-A$. And this happens if and only if $\alpha=-3$ and $\beta=9$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ and $B$ are linearly independent iff they are not parallel. Lets see when they are parallel:

$A$ and $B$ are parallel if $-9/\beta = \alpha/3 = 7/-7$ which implies that $\alpha=-3$ and $\beta=9$.

So for any values of $\alpha \ne -3$ and $\beta \ne 9$ they are not parallel, hence linearly independent.